# Is there any way to find the base prices for goods in Patrician III?

Tags: patrician-iii

I'm just wondering if there is a list somewhere of the base prices used for the goods in Patrician III, so I know what to set as a reasonable auto-buy/sell rates for goods. As I play the game, it seems to me that prices are calculated on some kind of curve about a 'base' price which is where there are "ample" supplies - scarcity below this 'ample' value would increase the price to a limit, and abundance would decrease the price.

I want to set my auto-buy prices at just below this 'base' value to ensure that I'm getting a good deal, and auto-sell prices at just above this 'base' value to prevent flooding the market.

I've found the wiki, which has a [list of 'highest and lowest'](http://patrician3.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_Prices) from watching fluctuations in gameplay, but can't figure out the base values from them.

Comment: if someone could tag this with "patrician-iii" - much appreciated :)

Comment: This question seems based in a flawed understanding of the game. Patrician 3's pricing works on a system of supply and demand. Pricing is inversely proportional to supply. As each town/port has less of something, you buy and sell for more there. **There aren't really "base prices" but rather fixed prices based on amount of supply.** What exactly are you looking for as an answer?

Comment: I understand that pricing fluctuates with availability - but it seems to me that there is a simple calculation around a "base" (or median, if you prefer). For example, it seems that you can make a pretty good go at buying meat for upto 1200, and sell at over 1300 (anything else either means you're not selling as fast as you can buy, or you're not buying enough to maintain a profit on each trip), indicating a base value of about 1250.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the "market clearing price" or in other words what the price would be if supply and demand were equal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_equilibrium

Comment: not really - that would be something driven by market forces - I'm looking for a value that is programmed into the game

Comment: the default buy/sell price in the warehouse looks like the closest to a preprogrammed buy/sell value and it is probably related to the base price used for market adjustment values - but some goods are moved more than the others so if you rely on them you'll find truckload of unsold stuff and nothing of the rare to obtains things

Comment: I wish I could remember well, but basically all I did was stop buying when the price went up significantly. As in, whenever there's low demand = low price. So I figure what is programmed is how many of each stuff, the current city actually needs, and how much does it have of that.

Comment: The german community has created a very extensive guide about this game. You can find it [here](http://downloads.patrizierforum.net/tippsammlung/Tippsammlung_2010.pdf). On page 71 you can find a table with price recommendations by people who definitely know how to play that game. It's unfortunately german but what are translators for. ;-) I'd love to write an answer and do the translation but I think the question here is not about recommendations so the answer would be wrong. Anyways, may the linked guide be useful for anyone reading this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchase

```
Beer         40
Bricks       80
Cloth       250
Fish        450
Grain       110
Hemp        350
Honey       120
Iron Goods  350
Leather     300
Meat       1100
Pig Iron   1000
Pitch        55
Pottery     200
Salt         30
Skins       750
Spices      400
Timber       60
Whale Oil    75
Wine        220
Wool        950
```

Sell

```
Beer         45
Bricks       90
Cloth       300
Fish        550
Grain       130
Hemp        400
Honey       140
Iron Goods  450
Leather     350
Meat       1250
Pig Iron   1200
Pitch        60
Pottery     220
Salt         35
Skins       900
Spices      450
Timber       80
Whale Oil   100
Wine        270
Wool       1050
```

( from https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=275838607 all credit to SinStar87)